# Complex module importing using Python

Tags: python, import

Hello fellow pythonistas,

I have an extended hierarchy of folders and subfolders of python scripts.
From any script, I need to be able to import any other python script inside any of these other folders.
I created the folders as packages because that was the recommended way for importing on many websites.

[image: a portion of the whole file structure]

A first "guerilla" way that I implemented and it works is the following:
1. I created a paths.py file where I append to sys.path every new folder.

```
import sys
import platform

if platform.system() == 'Linux':
    python_path = '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/QA/workspace/Site'
else:
    python_path = 'C:/Python27/projects/QA/Site'

#ACADEMIES
sys.path.insert(1, python_path + '/Academies/Tests')
sys.path.insert(2, python_path + '/Academies/Suites')
sys.path.insert(3, python_path + '/Academies/inc')
sys.path.insert(35, python_path + '/Academies/Academy_wall')
```

2.Inside every file I do the importing like this:

[image]

As you can see PyCharm is complaining about the imports; however when I run it it works.

Could it be possible to have a `paths.py` file that imports all the different packages in there and for all the other scripts to just call `import paths` and then from there import only the different files that I need like I do now?
Essentially, I want to do the same thing I'm doing in a more elegant and clear way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be possible, if you go `os.chdir(somePath)` you'll be able to import things from `somePath`. You can store paths where different scripts live and just `chdir` to places you need to. That's how I do it, anyway. It isn't very elegant but works. Also `os.walk` could be useful if you want to import everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

Well since all of the modules in these folders appear to depend on each other, then I would suggest making this entire set of folders a giant package, like so:

```
base
 |
 +--Academies
     |
     +- __init__.py
     +- FolderA
     |  +- __init__.py
     |  +- moduleA.py
     |  +- moduleB.py
     +- FolderB
     |  +- __init__.py
     |  +- moduleA.py
     |  +- moduleB.py
```

In each of these modules, refer to other modules like so:

```
# File: Academies/FolderA/moduleA.py
from Academies.FolderB import moduleA, moduleB
from . import moduleB as local_b  # moduleB is a naming conflict in this example so we rename it to local_b for the scope of this file.
```

With this scheme, you can still reference modules from any other module with relative ease.

If you need to run a module as `__main__`, you'll have to modify the way you call them.

With the folder above Academies (base in this example) as your working directory, you'll want to call moduleA in folderB like so:

```
C:\path\to\base>python -m Academies.FolderB.moduleA
```

Comment: I've never used PyCharm, but I assume there's a way of setting the base working directory.  If that's so, then it should stop throwing errors with this set up.

Comment: Thank you very much Jacob, I'll try it like you suggest and see how it goes.

Comment: @wehappyfew any updates on how it went?  Issues, etc?

Comment: As I am not so comfortable with advanced techniques in Python, I decided to simplify the concept. I make the module imports that I need in every occasion. It's not so much of an extra work and is more clear.